# First time Synchronization of eth client geth

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, mastering-ethereum

How to sync only few blocks of ethereum mainnet on geth? I don't complete blockchain to be sync and validated in my local machine. Is there any way to sync only few hundred blocks of mainnet in my local machine and run commands on it.

Comment: no , you can't. But if your friend has a synced node you could ask for a copy of `ancient` directory and get blocks and transactions. However you would have to read these files with your own programs. These files will take like 250Gigs

Answer (score 0):

[Syncing the current Ethereum mainnet using geth takes around 8 hours](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513). There is no partial state management with the out of the box geth, you need to have all of the blockchain or none of it.

Answer (score 0):

Before Ethereum moved to proof-of-work you had the option to synchronize in light mode. However, light mode is still not working in proof-of-stake. Your best alternative is passing `geth --syncmode snap`. This will start synchronizing at a much recent block than the genesis block. This should be a default parameter in your installation though. Make sure that you are not passing anything else and that you explicitly indicate this.